# Determine closest path between one address and a list of addresses

Tags: python

I have a list of addresses of all my employees.

Let's say, I receive a call and a client is located at address XYZ.

I would like to run a code to determine which employe is the closest.

Do I need Google Maps API? Any pointer where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the coordinates in latitude/longitude, you just find the geodesic (minimal path) via some simple calculation.

Comment: If you don't have the coordinates, you can look them up via the Google Maps API.

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample code that I can use to get started? Thank you for your time @MateenUlhaq

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://geopy.readthedocs.io/. It supports a variety of geocoders that can parse an address string and return coordinates. Once you've geocoded your addresses, you can use geopy.distance.distance() to calculate the distance in miles, km, etc.

```
from geopy import distance
newport_ri = (41.49008, -71.312796)
cleveland_oh = (41.499498, -81.695391)
print(distance.distance(newport_ri, cleveland_oh).miles)
>>>538.39044536
```

See https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#module-geopy.distance for more details.